# Search function in jsp dropdown spring MVC

Tags: java, jquery, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

Let me explain clearly what i am doing and what i want to achieve. I have jsp page, which holds two drop downs along with search button and a table with four columns. **Two of the table columns data is same as drop downs data**.

Initially when the jsp loads, these dropdowns set to ALL and by defaults all the results are showed in jsp table with single query fire to DB.

What i want is when a particular item is selected in both the dropdowns. I would like to display the results related to this search in table.

Do i need to fire a query for every search? because i have already got the total data at the beginning.

Any help would be appreciated?

Comment: it depends on the amount of rows. Whats the max amount?

Comment: Did you mean the row count? it depends and it might grow well in future.

Comment: You dont have to fire a DB query for each search.Instead you can hold the values in a Pojo after retrieving values from DB.Then when ever you enter search button you can do filtering on this pojo and return the updated tableObject to your View page

Answer (score 0):

Once you get all the data from DB

1. Store the values in a Pojo
2. Once your drop down is filled and pressed search button
3. Go for a ajax call and pass your drop down select  to your controller
4. Filter your new ArrayList\Object based on your drop down select and update
   your object which holds the value needed to populate your table
5. Populate your table with the updated object upon returning to your jsp.

Ajax Code

```
$.ajax({
         url:'filterTableData.do',
         cache:false,
         type: 'POST',
         dataType: 'text',
         data: ({'dropdownValue1' : dropdownValue1 ,'dropdownValue2' : dropdownValue2 }),
         error: function (res, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(' Error :' + errorThrown);
         },
         success: function(res){                    
                window.location.replace("jsptobedisplayed.do");
         }
       });
```

Java code -

```
@RequestMapping("/filterTableData")
@ResponseBody
public String deleteProd(@RequestParam String dropdownValue1,@RequestParam String dropdownValue2){
---->  your logic <--------}
```

Alternate was is once you press search , then go back to java and do the filter based on the drop down value and return the updated table object and populate the table.